# Three.js 2d controls x and y axis no rotation

Tags: three.js

Hello recently I started learning three.js. At the moment I have a project in which I'd like the user to move only in 2d (x axis and y axis without rotating the camera) although it is a 3d environment.

Is there any extension / plugin for three.js like OrbitControls but with the desired functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that with `OrbitControls`. The camera movement will be restricted to a plane perpendicular to the view direction. Use a pattern like this one:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 50 );

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.target.set( 0, 0, 0 ); // view direction perpendicular to XY-plane
controls.enableRotate = false;
controls.enableZoom = true; // optional
```

If you want the left mouse button to control the camera movement, then add this:

```
controls.mouseButtons = { PAN: THREE.MOUSE.LEFT, ZOOM: THREE.MOUSE.MIDDLE, ORBIT: THREE.MOUSE.RIGHT }; // swapping left and right buttons
```

You can modify the touch controls to match, but you will have to edit the `OrbitControls` source code to do so.

three.js r.89

Answer (score 1):

add this line if you need to enable pan:

```
controls.mouseButtons = {
    LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.PAN,
    MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.DOLLY,
    RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.ORBIT
}
```